# How to send keys to GUICtrl in remote desktop?

Tags: user-interface, desktop, send, autoit

I want to send <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> to my GUICtrl using AutoIt. When I do `Send("#r")` it works on my computer but not in remote desktop. I want to do it in the RDP session.

Code :

```
$host = "" ;<<<<<<< enter here the host name or ip address
$hGUI = GUICreate("Terminal server", 900, 700, -1, -1, $WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW + $WS_CLIPSIBLINGS + $WS_CLIPCHILDREN)
$oRDP = ObjCreate("MsTscAx.MsTscAx.2")
$oRDP_Ctrl = GUICtrlCreateObj($oRDP, 0, 0, 900, 700)
GUICtrlSetResizing(-1, $GUI_DOCKALL)
GUICtrlSetStyle($oRDP_Ctrl, $WS_VISIBLE)
$oRDP.DesktopWidth = 900
$oRDP.DesktopHeight = 700
$oRDP.Fullscreen = False
$oRDP.ColorDepth = 16
$oRDP.AdvancedSettings3.SmartSizing = True
$oRDP.Server = $host
$oRDP.UserName = "" ;<<<<<<< enter here the user name
$oRDP.Domain = ""
$oRDP.AdvancedSettings2.ClearTextPassword = ""
$oRDP.ConnectingText = "Connecting to " & $host
$oRDP.DisconnectedText = "Disconnected from " & $host
$oRDP.StartConnected = True
$oRDP.Connect()

GUISetState(@SW_SHOW, $hGUI)

$oShel = ObjCreate("shell.application")
$oShel_Ctrl = GUICtrlCreateObj($oShel, 0, 0, 900, 700)
GUICtrlSetStyle($oShel_Ctrl, $WS_VISIBLE)

While 1
    $nMsg = GUIGetMsg()
    Switch $nMsg
        Case $GUI_EVENT_CLOSE
        $oRDP.Disconnect()
     Exit
EndSwitch
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. I use PsExec.exe, it's easier !

**PS** : Don't forget the session's ID after options. Without it, PsExec will works but only in processes and will not make a window

Answer (score 0):

You will want to use the special shortcut key for use when connected via RDP. You can find a list here: [Remove Desktop Services Shortcut Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383500%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Try sending ALT+HOME:

```
Send("{ALT}{HOME}")
```

Comment: Does the RDP session window have focus (is it active)?

Comment: I tried with ControlFocus but it doesn't work :/ I will try with psExec on my computer I think

Comment: psExec appears but only in the process (service task manager) but there is no window. It's normal ?