# Azure VM UI automation

Tags: azure, virtual-machine, autoit

I migrate a script from a PC to the Azure cloud. This AutoIt script simulates keyboard and mouse operations. If I create a VM I can run the script using RDP so long as I keep the RDP window active. The UI however, is unavailable if the RDP window is not active on my PC so the script fails.

Is it possible to create a virtual desktop in Azure, which provides an UI at start up, without explicitly having been logged on?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to send keys to GUICtrl in remote desktop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24648783/how-to-send-keys-to-guictrl-in-remote-desktop)

Comment: This article has nothing to do with my problem. I would like to use autoit on a host, even if my RDT session is idle or I haven't even started it before.

Comment: Which is exactly what accepted answer enables. More options: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40759398/autoit3-could-not-send-text-to-windows-browse-dialog-on-virtual-machine/40807946#40807946), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45593966/how-can-i-run-an-autoit-script-on-windows-server-2016-without-the-remote-desktop/45672614#45672614), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25298491/4157124).

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53306092/2806502)?